# Javascript mobile detection

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a javascript alert box that asks the user if he would like to go to the mobile page or not. 
Right now I have this code :

```
if (screen.width <= 699) {
   alert document.location = "/mobile";
}
else {
     alert ("Thanks!");
}
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate. It's subtly different than the suggested duplicate article. The duplicate article discusses screen resolution and this question is about detecting mobile devices in general.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using following website's code:

- http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

What it does it checking client's userAgent string to find out if it's  mobile or not. It can detect most mobile devices also provide more ways to detect including jQuery, JavaScript, PHP, C# and ...

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 4):

You could test the `navigator.userAgent` property for mobile keywords to determine if the user is navigating your site through a device, and then he would have to `confirm` weather to navigate using the mobile or the full version of the site :

```
var isMobile = /iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
if(isMobile && confirm('do you want to see the mobile site?'))
    // navigate to the mobile version of the site
    location = '/mobile';
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

`if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Mobile/i)) document.location.href="./mobile"`

might work.